# How can I Install Tmux in Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cygwin, tmux

I'm trying to install Tmux under a Cygwin 64-bit installation on Windows 7 64-bit.
I'm following these instructions: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/tmuxInCygwin.html

I successfully compiled and installed libevent and ncurses, but I get this error when I try to `make` the patched version of tmux:

```
$ make
gcc  -I /usr/include/ncurses  -std=gnu99 -O0 -g -Wno-long-long -Wall -W -Wnested-externs -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wbad-function-cast -Winline -Wcast-align -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -Wno-pointer-sign    -o tmux.exe arguments.o attributes.o cfg.o client.o clock.o cmd-attach-session.o cmd-bind-key.o cmd-break-pane.o cmd-capture-pane.o cmd-choose-buffer.o cmd-choose-client.o cmd-choose-list.o cmd-choose-tree.o cmd-clear-history.o cmd-clock-mode.o cmd-command-prompt.o cmd-confirm-before.o cmd-copy-mode.o cmd-delete-buffer.o cmd-detach-client.o cmd-display-message.o cmd-display-panes.o cmd-find-window.o cmd-has-session.o cmd-if-shell.o cmd-join-pane.o cmd-kill-pane.o cmd-kill-server.o cmd-kill-session.o cmd-kill-window.o cmd-link-window.o cmd-list-buffers.o cmd-list-clients.o cmd-list-commands.o cmd-list-keys.o cmd-list-panes.o cmd-list-sessions.o cmd-list-windows.o cmd-list.o cmd-load-buffer.o cmd-lock-server.o cmd-move-window.o cmd-new-session.o cmd-new-window.o cmd-paste-buffer.o cmd-pipe-pane.o cmd-queue.o cmd-refresh-client.o cmd-rename-session.o cmd-rename-window.o cmd-resize-pane.o cmd-respawn-pane.o cmd-respawn-window.o cmd-rotate-window.o cmd-run-shell.o cmd-save-buffer.o cmd-select-layout.o cmd-select-pane.o cmd-select-window.o cmd-send-keys.o cmd-set-buffer.o cmd-set-environment.o cmd-set-option.o cmd-show-environment.o cmd-show-messages.o cmd-show-options.o cmd-source-file.o cmd-split-window.o cmd-string.o cmd-suspend-client.o cmd-swap-pane.o cmd-swap-window.o cmd-switch-client.o cmd-unbind-key.o cmd-unlink-window.o cmd-wait-for.o cmd.o colour.o control.o control-notify.o environ.o format.o grid-cell.o grid-view.o grid.o input-keys.o input.o job.o key-bindings.o key-string.o layout-custom.o layout-set.o layout.o log.o mode-key.o names.o notify.o options-table.o options.o paste.o resize.o screen-redraw.o screen-write.o screen.o server-client.o server-fn.o server-window.o server.o session.o signal.o status.o style.o tmux.o tty-acs.o tty-keys.o tty-term.o tty.o utf8.o window-choose.o window-clock.o window-copy.o window.o xmalloc.o xterm-keys.o osdep-unknown.o  compat/imsg.o compat/imsg-buffer.o compat/closefrom.o      compat/fgetln.o    compat/vis.o compat/unvis.o compat/strtonum.o     -lcurses -levent
tty-term.o:tty-term.c:(.rdata$.refptr.cur_term[.refptr.cur_term]+0x0): undefined reference to `cur_term'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:686: recipe for target 'tmux.exe' failed
make: *** [tmux.exe] Error 1
```

Is there any way I can work around that error?

Alternatively, is there another way to get Tmux working on Cygwin?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use tmux instead of screen? screen is in the repository and works out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to use tmux because it's required for the [Vim-R-Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) to work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This may be of interest to you:
tmux has been released as a cygwin package just recently!

Please have a look at the announcement at [on the Cygwin-Announce mailing list](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2014-03/msg00001.html);
you can now simply install tmux with the common cygwin `setup-{x86|x64}.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same issue.

I solved it by editing tty-term.c. Search for 'cur_term' and comment out the line.

It compiled fine after that. Not sure if there are any downsides to this. Haven't seen any yet!

Answer (score 1):

```
# download file on your machine:   
wget raw.github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg 

# change permissions to execute file in cygwin
chmod +x apt-cyg
 
# Install script to the /bin folder where - it will make the script available by name  
mv apt-cyg /bin

# Example: you can install something, similar as you can do it on Debian. # See how to install tmux:
apt-cyg install tmux
```

apt-cyg - supports more options:

list | cache  | remove | depends | listall  | download | listfiles |
show | mirror | search | install | category | rdepends | searchall

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [apt-cyg](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg/network) forks and simply do:

```
apt-cyg install tmux
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob and not a single suggestion mentioned previously worked.

The solution is to reinstall cygwin and chose package you're interested in right away (you will understand what to do while installing)

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: @karel: No, it’s not.  This answer says that, to add a patio to a house, you should tear down the house and build a new one (being sure to add the patio to the blueprint). It seems rather drastic, but, if nothing else works, sometimes you need to go nuclear.

Comment: I have 60K+ reputation at Ask Ubuntu and I'm still paranoid about using a VLQ flag at AU (+ I don't need to). The nuclear analog makes this question feel like a it's a VLQ though. Answering a question about pulling dog sleds with an answer recommending chihuahuas is inhumane and cruel, but it's an answer so I can't VLQ it, but I would definitely delete vote it.

Comment: This answer is indeed a duplicate of the accepted answer, but with misleading wording. Package install in Cygwin uses the same setup.exe installer used to install Cygwin itself and you end up going through a similar, but abbreviated installation sequence. Instead of "reinstalling" though, as this answer puts it, it will simply add the package to the current Cygwin install.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, installing tmux works now with the setup-{x86|x64}.exe.

Adding just so that I point out that it actually works, with a more recent post, than the one on Apr 2 2019. 
(I did not have to reinstall anything.)

Just put the drop-down to "Full" or "Not installed" and search for tmux, it was there.